# How to change a azure devops provisioned wiki to a published code wiki?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I’ve setup a provisioned wiki in my dev ops project. However I’ve realised I really should have setup a published code wiki instead.

Those were the two initial options, but I can’t see an option to change this?

Comment: Hi, friend. May I know the status of this? Does below method is help for you?

Comment: Sorry I have to had a chance to get back to this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way might be to...

1. clone the wiki repo locally (see:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops)
2. create a new empty git repo
3. add a remote for the new repo and push to that remote
4. then delete the provisioned wiki
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/provisioned-vs-published-wiki?view=azure-devops#delete-project-wiki

Comment: Thanks, but how do I delete the provisioned wiki?

Comment: That’s my issue I can’t delete the provisioned wiki and therefore start over ‍♂️

Comment: You would have to use the REST API to delete the project repository - 

For example: 

```DELETE https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=4.1``` 

Use the repository ID of the project wiki found using the previous step. Ensure that the repository ID matches the project wiki that you want to remove.

Answer (score 4):

install Azure CLI

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli
```

install devops extension

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

move to local project (the remote will be taken from .git directory)

```
cd C:\...\Workspaces\DevOps\ProjectName
```

auth

```
az login
```

get repository ID from id attribute (wiki has its own repo)

```
az devops wiki list
```

delete wiki

```
az repos delete --id af610cde-6c7c-40ba-8f59-d04b0f1ca51b
```

open AzureDevOps WIKI and select publish code option